# How to correctly retrieve the array length when searching both Drive and Shared Drives?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a scenario where I am searching for folders in Google Drive and also Shared Drive.  I have the following parameters - title contains "folder name", trashed = false and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"

I set this to create a new sheet to save the results. I think one of the "folder" is saved in a shared drive, so I can getting this error message: **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.**

How do I code this that if the "childFolder.owners[0].emailAddress" is not applicable (if the folder is in Shared Drives) and make this field blank and continue posting the array length? My code stops at childFolder.owners[0].emailAddress.

Apologies, this is my first time trying to search using Drive API - both Drive and Shared Drives. I hope my question makes sense, if not my apologies.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Here is my partial code:

```
do {
    var rows = [];
    var pageToken;
    var count = 0;

    var queryFolder1 = 'title contains "' + folderName2 + '" and trashed = false and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"';
    var driveFolders = Drive.Files.list({
      q: queryFolder1,
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken,
      orderBy: 'title',
      field: 'parents:[id]',
      includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
      supportsAllDrives: true
    });

    /* Create new sheet to save the output */
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderName2);
    var newSheetID = newSheet.getId();
    var newSheet1 = newSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    newSheet1.getRange('A2:L2').setValues([['Parent URL', 'File Name', 'File ID', 'File URL', "MimeType: File Type", 'Owner', 'Creation Date', 'Last Modified Date', 'Last Modified User', 'Last Modified User Email Address', 'Shared DriveId', 'Sharing User EmailAddress']]);

    /* Gather data */
    var driveFolder = driveFolders.items;
    if (driveFolder) {
      for (var x = 0; x < driveFolder.length; x++) {
        var childFolder = driveFolder[x];

        rows.push([childFolder.parents[0].id, childFolder.title, childFolder.id, childFolder.alternateLink, childFolder.mimeType, childFolder.owners[0].emailAddress, childFolder.createdDate, childFolder.modifiedDate, childFolder.lastModifyingUserName, childFolder.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress, childFolder.driveId, childFolder.sharingUser.emailAddress]);
      }
      newSheet1.getRange(3, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a property which does not exist.

> `childFolder.sharingUser.emailAddress` will throw a TypeError because `childFolder.sharingUser` does not exist.

You can check if it does before attempting to call it. For example:

Consider this part of your code,

```js
if (driveFolder) {
    for (var x = 0; x < driveFolder.length; x++) {
      var childFolder = driveFolder[x];
      var sharingUser = getSharingUser(childFolder);
      rows.push([childFolder.parents[0].id, childFolder.title, childFolder.id, childFolder.alternateLink, childFolder.mimeType, childFolder.owners[0].emailAddress, childFolder.createdDate, childFolder.modifiedDate, childFolder.lastModifyingUserName, childFolder.lastModifyingUser.emailAddress, childFolder.driveId, sharingUser.emailAddress]);
    }
    newSheet1.getRange(3, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
  }
```

where `getSharingUser` is:

```js
function getSharingUser(childFolder) {
  if (childFolder.sharingUser) {
    return childFolder.sharingUser
  } else return { emailAddress: "nobody" }
}
```

and `childFolder.sharingUser.emailAddress` changed to `sharingUser.emailAddress`

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but I still get this error message: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. It stops at childFolder.owners[0].emailAddress. How can I display the email address if it exists for a file or folder that is saved in Drive? The search I am doing is for both Drive and Shared Drives.

Comment: The problem you have is that whichever folder `childFolder` is there are some attributes which will be undefined,and the program will throw an error.  You should check they exist before attempting to call them.Or use [`try-catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block.